# Is it possible to exclude one series from a stacked line graph in Grafana

Tags: graph, grafana, influxdb, stacked-chart

I have a load of energy meters in the house, and a whole house meter, all of which report to influxdb, and I graph with grafana.

What I want is a graph with all meter readings stacked apart from the whole house meter that I want displaying on the same graph but not stacked.

Does anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: We're displaying stacked bar charts for industrial readings, but we developed our own plugin for that. I don't know if there's a plugin that will specifically do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Think I've sussed this, you can add a "Series Overide" then set Stacking to False, seems to do what I was after.